# Problema con fechas en LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-blade

Intento cambiar el formato de una fecha que me crea laravel con timestamps() que las guarda en formato 2000-01-01 00:00:00.

He intentado en la vista (plantilla blade) dentro del value de un input tipo date:

```
date('y-m-d', strtotime($user->created_at))
```

He probado a cambiar el formato en el controlador y pasarlo a la vista ya formateada pero le hago un dd() y me muestra la fecha en formato 2000-01-01 pero al llegar a la vista no se que pasa que no lo muestra bien.

Si le doy formato en la vista o en el controlador me sale esto por la consola del navegador:

> The specified value "2018-12-06 21:33:09" does not conform to the
>   required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Tambien he probado con esto:

```
$fecha = new Carbon($user->created_at);
$created = $fecha->toDateString();
```

Mismo resultado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes múltiples maneras. Yo te especifico algunas y tú eliges la que mejor creas conveniente:

1) A nivel de modelo, de forma global, con Carbon:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
}

public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Con esas funciones en la vista solo tendrías que mostrar:

```
{{ $user->created_at }}
```

2) A nivel de controlador, con Datetime:

```
$fecha_ejemplo = Datetime::createFromFormat('d M Y H:i', $user->created_at);
```

Datetime tiene también otra versión con (new):

```
$aux = new DateTime($user->created_at);
$fecha_ejemplo = $aux->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Un saludo

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias. Con tu ejemplo en nivel controlador no me ha funcionado, pero el del modelo si. Muchisimas gracias